# Meteor build generate only debug apk (not release) for project with Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, crosswalk

I recently added Crosswalk (v.1.2.0) to my meteor project, but I can't found a way to generate a **"release"** apk  which includes crosswalk.  When running `meteor build` I got these files:

a) `myapp-release-unsigned.apk`  <- Which works fine but doesn't include crosswalk

b) `/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk`  <- Which works fine and include crosswalk but I can't upload it to Google Play because is a debug version.

Any advice how to generate an APK in release version with Crosswalk?   So far I have found many solutions working for ionic (ionic run android --release) and cordova (cordova clean) but nothing related to meteor.  Also I have signed and aligned succesfully the debug.apk but the file still in debug mode.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm referencing xwalk as a dependency of a dummy package:

/packages/crosswalk/package.js   (Unique file inside self made crosswalk directory):

```
Package.describe({
   summary: "Makes your Cordova application use the Crosswalk WebView \
   instead of the System WebView on Android",
   version: '1.2.0'
});

 Cordova.depends({
   'cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview': '1.8.0'
});
```

I found a weird workaround to generate a release APK including Xwalk, just add and delete the xwalk package to meteor:

`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.8.0`

`meteor remove cordova:cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Then run `build` again and you will have a release-unsigned.apk (21MB) with Xwalk.